# How do you add items to Google Chrome Tab Context Menu?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

How do you add items to Google Chrome Tab Context Menu?

I would like to customize/add items to Google Chrome Tab Context Menu. I have looked through the API and I could not find how to do it. Is it possible to add functions to the tab context menu?

I would like to add options such as Bookmark Selected Tab, Close tab to the left to the Tab Context Menu.

Comment: You may want to edit your question to include information of your OS, the version of Chrome and the link to the extension so that people don't have to search the internet to answer your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is *Google Chrome Tab*? Do you mean the context-menu when you right-click a tab? If so, then there is no way to do it short of either hacking Chrome or getting a copy of the Chromium sources, modifying it, and compiling.

Themes and extensions are limited in what they can do with the actual chrome of the browser. For example, while they can add items to a *page’s* context-menu item, they cannot add one to the context-menus of the non-client areas such as the tabs or Wrench menu; they cannot even modify the dimensions of tabs, toolbars, etc.

Comment: Open https://meet.google.com/ in a Chrome-based browser and right-click on the page tab. There will be "Install Google Meet…" context menu at the bottom. That was what this question is about.

Comment: The "Install Google Meet" button is rather to install the PWA the website offers

Comment: Is this still the case in 2023?  No way to do this?

Comment: @KirillYunussov, I for one, have no idea, I stopped using Chrome years ago (why would anyone still use it when you know how evil it is? ) But I doubt things have improved since then; if anything, Google has made Chrome much **worse** and much less customizable. The new extension model locks things down so much in an attempt to break ad-blockers ("for security" ), extensions are practically useless now, they can barely do anything anymore. I *highly* doubt they've added the ability for extensions to modify the browser. 